# How to use babel with simple HTML file without build system?

Tags: compilation, ecmascript-6, babeljs, babel-polyfill

How to use babel with simple HTML file without build system?

The command-line TypeScript compiler can be installed as a Node.js package.

```
INSTALL
npm install -g typescript
COMPILE
tsc helloworld.ts
```

Than I added compiled file to HTML and it works fine.

How I can implement it with babel?

Fox example write es6 code, than compile in terminal and add this compiled script to index.hmtl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#installation - choose CLI

```
INSTALL
npm install -g babel-cli
COMPILE
babel helloworld.es6.js -d helloworld.js
```